# How to get data from non-http url on iOS

Tags: ios, rss, nsurlconnection, feed, nsurlrequest

I'm developing an app that gets RSS feeds from a website and the url has following form:

```
feed://feeds.<a_site_name>.org/...
```

As it isn't a http protocol so when I use NSURLConnection and NSUrlRequest to get data, it always returns nil data.

```
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:feedURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];    

NSOperationQueue *aqueue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:aqueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *resultJsonData, NSError *error)
         {

         }];
```

I have used ASIHttpRequest third party library to get, it works but I don't want to use third party library here.

Can I use any given framework on iOS or any simple code to get?

Answer (score 0):

A `feed://` URL is really just an HTTP or HTTPS URL, but intended to be read by an app that knows how to handle RSS feeds.  The way you solve this is to change the URL scheme to `http` (or `https`, if possible).  For example:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:feedURL
                                         resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];
components.scheme = @"https";
feedURL = [components URL];
```

Then try that URL, and if it fails, change the scheme to http and try again.